# Safari cannot open the page - The error was, "The URL can't be shown" - related to Deeplinks?

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking

So I am trying to use deeplinks in an iOS app like so (note, domain here is a dummy value):

```
static let redirectUrlStr = "domain://domain:success"
```

And

```
private let redirectUrl = URL(string: .redirectUrlStr)!
```

And I am passing this as a redirect to an AppAuth request:

```
let request = OIDTokenRequest(configuration: config!,
                              grantType: .refreshGrantType,
                              authorizationCode: nil,
                              redirectURL: self.redirectUrl,
                              clientID: .clientId,
                              clientSecret: nil,
                              scopes: [OIDScopeOpenID, OIDScopeProfile, OIDScopeEmail],
                              refreshToken: userCredentials.refreshToken,
                              codeVerifier: nil,
                              additionalParameters: nil)
```

This part all seems to work, and if I pass in a redirect URL like google.com, the redirect to google works.

However when attempting to use deeplinking I get the above error.

Now I think this should work -

I've got associated domains enabled in the capabilities portion of Xcode as such:

applinks:domain.com

And I have associated domains enabled in the App ID on Apple Developer

What is missing here? Do I need an apple-app-site-association file?

I've only worked with deeplinking once before so I'm not too clear on what I might be missing.

There is also an entitlements file with the associated domain information too.

Comment: I never coding on this topic but this might be helpful:-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8887086/error-launching-native-application-from-web-app-ios-url-cant-be-shown

Comment: Did you try with "domain://domain?success", because domain:success mean your port is "success" and it should be an Int, not a string

Comment: @CZ54 - that causes the app to crash.

Comment: what is the crash message?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to call your app with URL, you have to set `URLType` in your project info:

[image]

**Note** that you have to choose editor as `Role` of your `URL scheme`.
Now you can call your app with `domain://` and you can follow this url with any query or path parameters you what to pass to your app like: `domain://users?id=12`

If you need your original domain to forward to your app, for example: `www.domain.com/users` instead of `domain://users`, **YES** you need an **apple-app-site-association** uploaded to root of your host. So iOS can detect it and **if user prefers**, your app will open and the corresponding url passed to your application.

Both of these methods has it's own cons and pros. **Instagram** and **AppStore** use their original domain with an apple-app-site-association file associated. But **Google** is using URL scheme for tasks like **google sign-in**
[image]

Comment: Hrm, this is currently set in the app. It has an identifier, the url scheme set, and the role is set to editor. I'll have to look into if something wrong with this process is part of the issue

Comment: You can test it. Try to open domain:// in safari and see if it works. If not, it would be greatif you get some screenshots and let me see if I can find the issue ;) (cover sensitive data before upload)

Comment: How is it going @AndrewAlexander? Did you find the issue?

Comment: The URL scheme already existed before I posted the question, so I'm not quite sure what to test here. And yes, when I put in "domain://" it links me to the authentication page. However, when I try to authenticate using the above OIDTokenRequest, I get the same error message. So I don't think URL scheme by itself is the problem.

Comment: What would you like screenshots of?

Comment: This isn't the solution, but it did lead me to the solution so I am awarding the points to it. Basically during the hand-off, the same URL scheme identifier already exists and this is causing what Apple describes as "odd behavior" - when I switched to a new URL scheme identifier, everything immediately worked.

Comment: You should use a unique one. I face that before. Apple put an identifier for it but it seams useless

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be related with your app's URL Scheme handling. If you don't update your plist to inform operating system about your handling of `domain` URL scheme then it'll be seen as a mistyped URL. Try to add `domain` to your `URL Types -> URL Schemes` of your `Info.plist` file. You can do this via:

```
  <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.domain</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>domain</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
  </array>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there I am using a deep-link url generate by fire base.

I can open this url in google and safari my code is

```
/// Deepl link Shared Link
    func deepLinkShare(_ data: CSSharedObject, sender: Any, isVideoDetail: Bool = false) {
        let button = sender as? UIButton
        button?.startAnimating()
        let videoLink = SHAREURL + "video/" + data.videoSlug + "?videoId=" + String(data.videoId)
        guard let link = URL(string: videoLink) else { return }
        let dynamicLinksDomain = DEEPLINKDOMAIN
        let linkBuilder = DynamicLinkComponents(link: link, domain: dynamicLinksDomain)
        linkBuilder.iOSParameters = DynamicLinkIOSParameters.init(bundleID: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!)
        linkBuilder.iOSParameters?.customScheme = CUSTOMURLSCHEME
        linkBuilder.iOSParameters?.minimumAppVersion = "1.0"
        linkBuilder.navigationInfoParameters?.isForcedRedirectEnabled = false
        linkBuilder.iOSParameters?.appStoreID = "123456789"
        linkBuilder.analyticsParameters = DynamicLinkGoogleAnalyticsParameters(source: "asfdsf",
                                                                               medium: "video",
                                                                               campaign: "Share")
        linkBuilder.socialMetaTagParameters = DynamicLinkSocialMetaTagParameters()
        linkBuilder.socialMetaTagParameters?.title = data.videoTitle
        linkBuilder.socialMetaTagParameters?.descriptionText = data.videoShortDescription
        linkBuilder.socialMetaTagParameters?.imageURL = data.thumbNailimage
        linkBuilder.androidParameters = DynamicLinkAndroidParameters(packageName: ANDROIDAPPBUNDLE)
        linkBuilder.options = DynamicLinkComponentsOptions()
        linkBuilder.options?.pathLength = .short
        guard let longDynamicLink = linkBuilder.url else { return }
        DynamicLinkComponents.shortenURL(longDynamicLink, options: nil) { url, _, error in
            button?.stopAnimating()
            guard let url = url, error == nil else { return }
            /// item to be shared
            let shareItems: Array = [url.absoluteString] as [Any]
            self.openSharePopUp(sender, sharedItems: shareItems, isVideoDetail: isVideoDetail)
        }
    }
```

1. CSShared Object is one which has a custom object
2. data.videoSlug is the item data which is used to construct url
3. DEEPLINKDOMAIN is the domain of deeplink Domain generate by fire base it
4. CUSTOMURLSCHEME is the custom scheme generate for that particular application

This then can be opened in application by using the delegate of fire base Dynamic linking

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?,
                     annotation: Any) -> Bool {
        if let dynamicLink = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().dynamicLink(fromCustomSchemeURL: url) {
            /// Open the dynamic link url in your application

            return true
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that due to the URL scheme identifier already existing in the App Store, it is considered a duplicate and this is causing what Apple describes as, "odd behavior".

Switching to a more unique URL scheme identifier fixed the problem immediately.